# How to write s-lim with the the limiting value (for eg. $n \rightarrow \infty)$) right under the s-lim

Tags: subscripts, code

I have this

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \DeclareMathOperator{\slim}{s-lim}
  $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\slim} A_n= B$
  \end{document}
```

I dont want to write \underset{...} always rather I would like to code it in the preamble and be able write any limit

(say,

```
n\to \infty
```

or

```
x \to 0
```

or

```
bla-bla-bla
```

) right under \slim by writing something like \slim_{bla-bla-bla} or \slim\limits_{bla-bla-bla}. \slim\limits_{...} is not giving me the argument under the \slim. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `\DeclareMathOperator*` and then write `\slim_{n\to\infty}`. In display-math settings, the `n\to\infty` "argument" will be placed immediately below "s-lim"; in inline-math settings, the argument will be placed to the right of, in the subscript position, "s-lim". That's exactly how `\lim` is defined as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\slim}{s-lim}

\begin{document}
\[
\slim_{n\to\infty} A_n= B
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course this won't give the limits under the `\slim` in inline math, but that is consistent with the behaviour of `\lim`.

Comment: @moewe - My working assumption is indeed that `\slim` should behave exactly the way that `\lim` does.

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot it worked. It is behaving exactly like \lim. Just to learn about it, would you mind explaining what does the * in \DeclareMathOperator* signifies?

Comment: @TijuCherianJohn - Without the asterisk, the operator would place its argument to the right-hand subscript position in display-math mode.